# Can kotlin interface detects, on which class is attached to, on its own?

Tags: kotlin, generics

I have generic interface...

```
interface Parent<T> {
    fun function(entity: T): Int
}
```

And when I implement functionality with some child class...

```
class Other : Parent<Other> {
    override fun function(entity: Other): Int {
        return 42
    }
}
```

I'm bothered with the fact that I have to pass the same class type while implementing the interface... I would really like for the interface to be able to detect on which class is attached on its own without me providing the same type again...

I would like code something like this...

```
class Other : Parent {
    override fun function(entity: Other): Int {
        return 42
    }
}
```

Is it possible in kotlin to do that in some form?

Comment: It is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Not in the general case, but sometimes when a generic is fully constrained by another: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#underscore-operator-for-type-arguments